# Clearing row of data from jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

So im trying to clear a row of data in a jTable, but when i get to the last row and clear it, it clears... but gives me an error " Row index out of range" need help please :D

```
    //Get table model.
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblStock.getModel();
    //Create variable.
    int selectedProduct = tblStock.getSelectedRow();
    //Remove selected row.
    model.removeRow(selectedProduct);
    //Clear selection.
    tblStock.clearSelection();
    //Set intervals.
    tblStock.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
    tblStock.setRowSelectionInterval(selectedProduct, selectedProduct);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's look at this again:

```
int selectedProduct = tblStock.getSelectedRow();
model.removeRow(selectedProduct);
tblStock.setRowSelectionInterval(selectedProduct, selectedProduct);
```

Seems like you are removing a row and then trying to select it. Indeed, the index is most likely out of range after you have removed it.